# Let SDL WEB 8 Rich Text field support HTML 5

Tags: web8, rtf

SDL WEB 8 Rich Text field still stick to HTML 4. Behind this field, WEB 8 use tidy html to format the HTML content. But based on http://www.html-tidy.org/, Tidy solution do support HTML 5, is it possible we just upgrade SDL WEB 8 tidy package version to get the HTML 5 support?

The main feature we expect here is let tag a can wrap tag div. Right now, if we input `<a><div>test</div></a>`, it will be auto format to `<a></a><div>test</div>`. We want to avoid this kind of format.

Comment: SDL Web rich text format areas are not HTML 4, per se. The text field supports XML in the XHTML namespace which is often templated to HTML4, XHTML, or HTML5.

Comment: If interested, the community can follow a related SDL Tridion Sites Idea: https://community.sdl.com/ideas/sdl-tridion-dx-ideas/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/i/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/support-html5-in-rich-text-field.

Answer (score 4):

If it is possible, I doubt it would be supported because there could be dependencies inside the CME that aren't tested against the latest Tidy. However, IIRC, Tidy is not used by Tridion or Web. It is a custom implementation.

Also, very unofficially and not yet committed to the Web 9 release, is a new RTF editor on top of Textbox.io. This rumour has been started at the SDL India Meet 2017 last week. Again this is still early stages and not committed by SDL for the Web 9 release, but is certainly on the product roadmap for the near future.

Comment: The fact that SDL has considered rich text format area options is true. We haven't committed to a specific editor nor date, though, so thanks for qualifying any commitment for such a replacement. The RTF replacements, however, don't necessarily guarantee HTML5 support or a change in wrapping behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Currently SDL Web 8 indeed does not fully support HTML5, certainly from a Rich Text field standpoint.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263064/html5-tags-are-not-working-in-rtf-field-for-tridion-2011 for a few hints on how to get the majority of HTML5 features working, but you won't be able to support wrapping Block Level elements in an Anchor element.

Is there a specific reason why you need `<a><div>...</div></a>`, or could you simply get away with `<a><span>...</span></a>`?

Comment: It is a typical way we mark an entire block to be clickable. Most of the time we use DIV to wrap an block, which contains multiple paragraphs. SPAN couldn't handle this kind of user case.

Comment: @qchen01 not as clean as HTML5, but you could simply set `display:block` for the `a` and `span` tags, so they will behave the same as a `div`

Comment: Tried `<a style="display:block"><div>test</div></a>`, but still doesn't work.

Comment: No you can use `<a style="display:block">...</a>` which is equivalent to `<a><div>...<div></a>`, alternatively you could use: `<a><span style="display:block">...</span></a>` (and use classes with a CSS preferably ;o)